# java reflection MethodUtils

Tags: java, jpa, reflection, eclipselink

I have requirement to set the create date and created user (same for update).

In my entity manager custom code, I would like to access object tree

```
class Person {

private Contact personContact;
private Phone personPhone;
private List<Address> personAddressList;
}
```

And each class have same attributes like createDate, createUser, updateDate, updateUser

I want to recursivly check all object which are not null and set the create or update information.

I tried to do using

```
MethodUtils.invokeMethod(request, "setCreateTs", DateUtils.currentJavaTime());
```

This will set only the person object, how should I do for other object tree like contact or phone if they are not null.

Comment: You will have to add the logic to traverse your object graph to the appropriate set methods that you intend to call through java reflection.

Answer (score 0):

you must initialize all with constructor, getter and setter methods..here an example.

```
    public class Person {

private Contact personContact;
private Phone personPhone;
private List<Address> personAddressList;

public Person(Contact personContact, Phone personPhone, List<Address> personAddressList)
{
 if(personContact == null)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Contact null!");
 if(personPhone == null)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Person Phone null!");
 if(personAddressList.size() == 0 || personAddressList.isEmpty() || personAddressList == null)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Person Address List null or empty");
 this.personContact = personContact;
 this.personPhone = personPhone;
 this.personAddressList = personAddressList;
}
public Contact getContact()
{
return personContact;
}
public Phone getPhone()
{
return personPhone;
}
public List<Address> getPersonAddressList()
{
 if(personAddressList.size() == 0 || personAddressList.isEmpty() || personAddressList == null)
 return new ArrayList<Address>(); //EMPTY LIST
 return personAddressList;
}
public void setContact(Contact cont)
{
 this.personContact = cont;
}
public void setPhone(Phone phone)
{
this.personPhone = phone;
}
public void setPersonAddressList(List<Address> list)
{
this.personAddressList = list;
}
}
```

Create Object Person with the constructor like this.

```
Person person = new Person(contact, phone, list);
```

And than you can get all that you want with getter methods, If you create object with constructor you can not write setter methods